# Why is .NET unable to decode this string when Java can "Hi%E1"?

Tags: .net, asp.net, encoding, uri

My problem is with .Net Http/Uri libraries not being able to decode or unescape this character sequence: "Hi%E1". 
Neither **Uri.UnescapeDataString** nor **HttpUtility.UrlDecode** can do it.

Although I have a solution to get around this problem ( [URL decoding confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221849/url-decoding-confusion) ) I would like to understand why it is failing.

The 1st test here throws an exception! The second just fails.

```
Assert.That(Uri.UnescapeDataString("Hi%E1"), Is.EqualTo("Hiá"));
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Hi%E1").ShouldBe("Hiá");
```

There is nothing in the docs to indicate that **UnescapeDataString** or **UrlDecode** are restricted to character sets or any reason why these tests would fail. However, from testing, it would appear that HttpUtility assumes UTF-8 (or some other) encoding.

The Java equivalent works! Probably because it allows an encoding to be set.

```
URLDecoder.decode("Hi%E1","windows-1252");    // this works btw, ie passes tests
```

Which looks like a very sensible move considering the .Net work-around (see URL above)

Are the .Net implementations of these methods just crap and .Net devs just have to write their own - or am I missing something?

BTW Everything I know of in IIS set to **UTF-8**, and Chinese/Japanese characters show fine, so I don't yet know how it could it be that this URI consists of windows-1252 encoded characters. If I could fix the URI to contain UTF-8 encoding, that would be a better way of fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) you can also set the encoding using the HttpUtility.UrlDecode.

Although, that seems to simple if you're running into problems... just making sure you saw the overload.

Comment: I figured it'd be more complicated than that. Just wanted to make sure you weren't missing the obvious. We all do once in a while.

Comment: Oops, no I didn't see the overlaod

Answer (score 2):

**Addendum**

I discovered the underlying issue to this problem.
I was using 'escape' in javascript - it's deprecated, don't use it.

**escape('á')** returns '%E1' - which is a *windows-1252* encoding (ie it will fail or return the wrong character when using the methods above eg **HttpUtility.UrlDecode** unless you are able to specify 'windows-1252' in the overload)

**encodeURI('á')** returns '%C3%A1' - which is a *UTF-8* encoding. Which will work and all your troubles will go away. The methods above will work without throwing exceptions or producing the wrong character.

Dreaming: Wouldn't it be nice if the **Uri.UnescapeDataString** specified which escape character was the problem? My URI at the time of diagnosis was 23,000 characters long. "Invalid URI" is not such a helpful message in that scenario.

Comment: I'm more curious about how do you get a 23k char URI?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work as specified...

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Hi%E1", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"));
```

Edit: Answer to comment.

If you use Reflector on HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string) you see that it uses UTF8 as the default Encoding. (As it should.)

```
//From Reflector (System.Web)
public static string UrlDecode(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return UrlDecode(str, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: Yep, I didn't see the overload, you can also do this:
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Hi%E1", Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
The no-arg should be obselete, as whatever the default is, nobody knows!

Comment: Thank you, yes. And the real question for the underlying issue is, how did I manage to create data that was encoded in the non-default encoding...