# PHP function to decode strings with different encodings

Tags: php, escaping, decoding, urldecode

I have a couple of encoded strings with different encoding types for example: `Zubeh%F6r` and `Zubeh%C3%B6r`, which both need to be decoded to `Zubehör`. 
The first example string can be decoded with the PHP function urldecode() but the only solution I found for decoding the second string was with the javascript function unescape().

**Question 1:** How can I decode the second type of string with a PHP function?

**Question 2:** How can I make a PHP function where I can pass in a text with these two encoding types and the function automatically decodes the text correctly?

Comment: They're both URL encoded, and urldecode should decode both of them. This answer is asking about the same two characters, and although they're dealing with it in C# rather than PHP, it may still be informative. There's also an answer there that may be able to be adapted to PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221849/url-decoding-confusion

Answer (score 0):

I could write a book about messed up encoding by now ...

Q1: it is double encoded, as you can see from the amount of "weird" characters.

Q2: that is quite a task. You could use some of the mbstring functions of PHP in order to check the type of encoding you have and then all change it to the one you want. Yet, when I recall it correctly, there are some issues in terms of detecting and changing all properly. There were some issues with this stuff in some projects in the past.

Some point of reference:
https://secure.php.net/manual/de/book.mbstring.php